# Cell casting throws exception

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to load information to a tableView, and I get an exception because some information in the cell isn't initialized when I cast to it. and this is my code :

The code for the view containing the tableView:

```
    private func populateActiveChats()
        {
            let loggedOnUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            let ref = Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.child(loggedOnUserID!)

            ref.observe(.value, with:
                    { (snapshot) in

                        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                        {

                            if (self.chatsDictionary.keys.contains(child.key) == false)
                            {
                                let chatValueDictionary = child.value as? NSDictionary
                                self.AddChatToCollections(chatAsDictionary: chatValueDictionary)
                                self.DispatchQueueFunc()
                            }


                        }
                })
        }


    func AddChatToCollections(chatAsDictionary: NSDictionary!)
            {
                if chatAsDictionary == nil
                {
                    return
                }
                let contactName = 

chatAsDictionary[Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_NAME] as! String
            let newMsgs = chatAsDictionary[Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.NUM_OF_UNREAD_MSGS] as! Int
            let contactID = chatAsDictionary[Constants.Chat.ChatRoomsLite.CONTACT_ID] as! String

            let chatToAdd = PrivateChatLiteObject(chattingWith: contactName, ContactID: contactID, unreadMessages: newMsgs, LastMSG: "")


            chatsDictionary[contactID] = chatToAdd
            chatsIndex.append(contactID)
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            let cell = ChatsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chat_room_cell", for: indexPath) as! PrivateChatUITableViewCell


            let indexedID = chatsIndex[indexPath.row]
            cell.ContactName.text = chatsDictionary[indexedID]?.GetContactName()

            cell.ContactID = chatsDictionary[indexedID]?.GetContactID()
            return cell

        }
```

And in my PrivateChatUITableViewCell:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            let cell = ChatsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chat_room_cell", for: indexPath) as! PrivateChatUITableViewCell

            //cell.ContactImageView = UIImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString(contactImg)
            let indexedID = chatsIndex[indexPath.row]
            cell.ContactName.text = chatsDictionary[indexedID]?.GetContactName()

            cell.ContactID = chatsDictionary[indexedID]?.GetContactID()
            //cell.PopulateCell()
            return cell

        }

public func PopulateCell()
    {
        let currentID = Constants.refs.currentUserInformation?.uid
        Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.child(currentID!).child(ContactID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in ...})

}
```

The code crashes when it reaches the `Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.child(currentID!).child(ContactID!)`

line because ContactID isn't initialized.

This is being called when casting cell to `PrivateChatUITableViewCell`

I haven't changed my code and this used to work, so I am not sure what changed or what I am doing wrong. Where should my code be fixed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you know *why* things are crashing - you are force-unwrapping something that's nil - but instead you are trying to fix it by saying "it worked before, why not now". Maybe just accept *that* and instead see if you can (a) remove the force-unwrapping or (b) find out why it is nil?

Comment: I am casting the cell to a specific cell. So you're saying it is calling the  C'tor?  and then because the ContactID is nil it crashes, right? So I Need to remove the PopulateCell from the init? function and call it after I instantiate both members in  cellForRowAt ?

Comment: I'm saying your own words and code lead me to think the `ContactID` is nil and your force-unwrapping is causing the crash. Why is it nil? I honestly cannot say - you haven't provided the data behind it. (This is why I said I'm pretty sure you know the why.) Most times a table view is based on a data array the app somehow sets up. That data array *ideally* shouldn't have optionals in it, period. But in the situation where you simply cannot "nil-proof" it, you probably should provide checks *before* calling `cellForRowAt`.